# Group policy not updating on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, kerberos

I have a small solution for one of our customers.
There are 3 servers, a Domain Controller, Session Host Server and a Sage Server.

Just recently we've noticed that group policies are no longer applying to users logging in to the Session Host server. As such, profile redirection isn't occuring which is causing a whole host of other issues.

If I run `gpupdate /force` I get the following response...

```
 The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not authenticate to 
 the Active Directory service on a domain controller. (LDAP Bind function call failed).
 Look in the details tab for error code and description.
```

A quick look in the system error logs shows me kerberos errors all over the place...

[image]

The event 1006 I can see seems to show 'Invalid Credentials'...

[image]

Although I'm unsure what credentials it's complaining about.

I've checked with my colleagues and nobody is owning up to having changed anything, so i'm stumped as to what has caused this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Microsoft, this issue may be caused by a whole host of faults. I will paste a link below where you can exhaust the suggestions and see if it fixes your problems.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727283(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced a similar problem.

The relevant thread can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1061248/group-policy-error-1006-with-error-code-49), containing possible solutions.